# how to add a timer for each tableview cell that updates everytime a user scrolls?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I'm trying to add a time counter to each of my tableview cells. 
I have enabled scrolling with pagination, each cell of my tableview is full screen.

What I want:
When a user is on a cell, the time counter starts automatically and when they scroll, the time counter stops, and another one for the following cell starts...etc

I also want to keep a record of the time elapsed.

what I tried: 
to add a timer to the view controller instead of tableview, I have 2 problems:

1) The timer is not reset when I swipe up although I invalidate it as you can see below

2) The timer starts before the first cell has loaded its content from the server

```
var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0

@IBOutlet var countingLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    countingLabel.text = String(counter)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
        print("Swipe Left")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettings", sender: self)
    } else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up {
        print("Swipe Up")
        timer.invalidate()
        counter = 0
        countingLabel.text = String(counter)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down {
        print("Swipe Down")
    }
}

@objc func updateCounter() {
    counter += 1
    countingLabel.text = String(counter)
}
```

I want a timer to fire for each cell of my tableview, and i want to keep the elapsed time in a variable that I can use elsewhere

Comment: Don't put volatile objects like timers in the **view** (the cel)l. Cells can be deallocated immediately. Put the timer in the **model** (the data source).

Comment: i didn't put it in the cell. It is attached to the viewcontroller instead of the tableview as this was easier for me to code. but I'm still unable to resolve the problems described above( invalidating the timer when swipeup action is detected and starting the timer when the table has loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can handle `timers` in each `UITableViewCell`.

**Create a custom `UITableViewCell`**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    //MARK: Internal Properties
    var handler: ((Int)->())?

    //MARK: Private Properties
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var counter = 0 {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label.text = "\(self.counter)"
                self.handler?(self.counter)
            }
        }
    }

    func configure(with counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.setTimer()
    }

    private func setTimer() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {[weak self] (timer) in
            self?.counter += 1
        })
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. I've created a `label` that will update the `counter` value in `UI`.
2. `handler` - it will and store the updated `counter` value somewhere (in `ViewController`, explained further) when the `cell` is moved out of the screen
3. `timer` - schedule the `timer` in the `cell` with `timeinterval = 1`
4. `counter` - current `counter` value for each `cell`

**In the `ViewController`,**

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let numberOfCells = 20
    var timerArr = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timerArr = [Int](repeating: 0, count: numberOfCells)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfCells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.configure(with: self.timerArr[indexPath.row])
        cell.handler = {[weak self] (counter) in
            self?.timerArr[indexPath.row] = counter
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code,

1. `timerArr` - keeps track of the `counter` value for each `cell` in the `tableView`.
2. In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, the `counter` for each `cell` is updated using the `handler` we created previously in `CustomCell`